# Are carpet and pad salvageable with partial flooding?

Tags: carpet, flooding

We had a storm that caused a flood in one part of the basement where the water level actually went above a window and started coming in through it. I immediately shopvacd it and pulled up the carpet and pad to dehumidify and run a blower over, but as you can see from the pics they're pretty wet and I'll have to clean up the dirt the water brought in as well. Is this carpet even worth salvaging or is it better just to recarpet this room?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Depends on the cost of the carpet.  The padding is cheap and might just get new padding.  Cost of cleaning/drying the carpet to cost of new is different.

Comment: Personally, I'd just recarpet, unless you can be confident that you dried it out *tout de suite.*

Answer (score 2):

If both the carpet and pad can be thoroughly dried prior to mildew growth, it should be fine to reuse. I had the same thing happen and laid out the carpet and pad flat, vacuumed it dry, elevated it outdoors on sawhorses to dry. I then re-laid the pad and stretched the carpet back in place.